# Is it possible to only allow img tags in html comment post?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I have a comment form on my website which, at the moment I filter out all html and turn it into plain text and also replace bad words with funny words. I want to be able to allow users to post images. I couldn't see how to incorporate this to the comment page so have set it up on a separate page just dedicated to users posting images. But, I still don't want to allow any other html except img. Also, protect from sql injection.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: So I'm perfectly fine to post an image containing a "bad word"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two decent methods would be using [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) or [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). Both filter HTML very well and are highly customizable to suit your needs.

With purifier (I speak from experience as I have used it) it will allow you to add something like:

```
img[src,alt,title]
```

To the allowed tags property, which allows only those attributes in the `img` tag. See the website for more information / usages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pass a list of allowable tags to php's `strip_tags()` function:

```
$clean_text = strip_tags($html_text, "<img>") ;
```

Comment: Yes, you can, but I'd rather not have all kinds of javascript in `on*` attributes on my site. Be sure to clear out any attribute except for `src` (and possibly `alt`/`title`)

Comment: didnt even think of that. how would u do that?